# Test a view model with livedata, coroutines (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2, viewmodel, android-livedata, coroutine

I've been trying to test my view model for several days without success.

**This is my view model :**

```
class AdvertViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val parentJob = Job()

    private val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = parentJob + Dispatchers.Default

    private val scope = CoroutineScope(coroutineContext)

    private val repository : AdvertRepository = AdvertRepository(ApiFactory.Apifactory.advertService)

    val advertContactLiveData = MutableLiveData<String>()

    fun fetchRequestContact(requestContact: RequestContact) {
        scope.launch {
            val advertContact = repository.requestContact(requestContact)
            advertContactLiveData.postValue(advertContact)
        }
    }
}
```

**This is my repository :**

```
class AdvertRepository (private val api : AdvertService) : BaseRepository() {

    suspend fun requestContact(requestContact: RequestContact) : String? {

        val advertResponse = safeApiCall(
            call = {api.requestContact(requestContact).await()},
            errorMessage = "Error Request Contact"
        )

        return advertResponse
    }
}
```

**This is my view model test :**

```
@RunWith(JUnit4::class)
class AdvertViewModelTest {
    private val goodContact = RequestContact(...)

    private lateinit var advertViewModel: AdvertViewModel

    private var observer: Observer<String> = mock()

    @get:Rule
    var instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        advertViewModel = AdvertViewModel()
        advertViewModel.advertContactLiveData.observeForever(observer)
    }

    @Test
    fun fetchRequestContact_goodResponse() {
        advertViewModel.fetchRequestContact(goodContact)

        val captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String::class.java)

        captor.run {
            verify(observer, times(1)).onChanged(capture())
            assertEquals("someValue", value)
        }
    }
}
```

**The method mock() :**

```
inline fun <reified T> mock(): T = Mockito.mock(T::class.java)
```

**I got this error :**

> Wanted but not invoked: observer.onChanged();
>   -> at com.vizzit.AdvertViewModelTest.fetchRequestContact_goodResponse(AdvertViewModelTest.kt:52)
>   Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

I don't understand how to retrieve the result of my query.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to write a `OneTimeObserver` to observe livedata from the `ViewModel`

```
class OneTimeObserver<T>(private val handler: (T) -> Unit) : Observer<T>, LifecycleOwner {
    private val lifecycle = LifecycleRegistry(this)

    init {
        lifecycle.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME)
    }

    override fun getLifecycle(): Lifecycle = lifecycle

    override fun onChanged(t: T) {
        handler(t)
        lifecycle.handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
    }
}
```

After that you can write an extension function:

```
fun <T> LiveData<T>.observeOnce(onChangeHandler: (T) -> Unit) {
    val observer = OneTimeObserver(handler = onChangeHandler)
    observe(observer, observer)
}
```

Than you can check [this `ViewModel` class](https://github.com/coroutineDispatcher/pocket_treasure/blob/master/setup_module/src/test/java/com/sxhardha/setup_module/setup_pkg/SetupViewModelTest.kt) class that I have from a project to check what's going on with your `LiveData` after you act (when) with invoking a method.

As for your error, it just says that the `onChanged()` method is not being called ever.

Comment: Thanks I'm trying to implement your solution, where can I find AppCoroutineDispatchers?

Comment: oh just ignore that. because it's just a data class that has `Dispatchers.IO` or `Dispatchers.Main` but if you aren't using coroutines you don't need it at all.

Comment: Okay, I did what you said but nothing happens, my test is always green : https://ctxt.io/2/AABArrklFA

Comment: If it is green, than the test has passed.

Comment: I mean, no matter what I write in assertEquals ("test", it) it's always green.

Comment: yes, because you haven't acted, just arranged and asserted: After the `advertViewModel.fetchRequestContact(goodContact)` you have to write something like this: `when(repository.requestContact()).thenReturn("string_you_want")`. After that you can assert with "string_you_want"

Comment: To avoid situations with always green tests because of not called assert I can suggest to add variable `var isCaptorCalled = false`, which is set to `true` in captor. In the end of test you need additional test `assertTrue(isCaptorCalled)` that will crash you test in case your captor wasn't called.